# Why innermostAssembly is empty?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I have implemented Azure App Insights for my .NET 6 application. Does anyone know why `innermostAssembly` is empty? This screen is from "Monitoring" > "Logs" in Azure Application Insights

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it has no inner exception.

Take this example code:

```cs
var simpleException = new Exception("simpleException");
var nestedException = new Exception("nestedException", new Exception("innerexceptino"));

_telemetryClient.TrackException(simpleException);
_telemetryClient.TrackException(nestedException);
```

This will be the result:

The logged `simpleException` won't have the innermost fields filled, the logged `nestedException` will.